# What tools are available for collaborative game development?

Tags: tools

Are there any tools that would let multiple people edit things like sprites or code at the same time? Perhaps something that works with services that host code.

Comment: Flagging this for CW.

Comment: -1, Can you be more specific in what you're looking for?  Are you looking for an actual simultaneous user editing environment for textures?  A network supported multi-user code IDE?  Or just something more mundane like some cloud storage so people can work on "the same file" at different times?

Comment: I can't answer because it's closed (not sure why, it's a great question).  But here are some real-time collaboration game editors.
http://superpowers-html5.com/index.en.html

https://sparklinlabs.itch.io/craftstudio

https://playcanvas.com/plans

Answer (score 6):

Surely a source control system is what you need?  Check-ins, check-outs, version history, that sort of thing.

Answer (score 4):

**Version Control:**

Try [GitHub](https://github.com/) for version control. It's fantastic -- you can use [git](http://git-scm.com/) or [svn](http://subversion.tigris.org/) (whichever you're more comfortable with) and your repositories get free [issue tracking](http://github.com/blog/411-github-issue-tracker), [wikis](http://github.com/blog/699-making-github-more-open-git-backed-wikis) and cool [visual graphs](http://github.com/blog/39-say-hello-to-the-network-graph-visualizer). The only downside is that if you want your project hosted privately, [you have to pay](http://github.com/plans). (It's as low as $7/month as of this writing; [we](http://github.com/lostdecade) pay and find it well worth the cost.)

**File Sharing:**

We also love and use [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/referrals/NTUxMTM0Mjk). It supports Windows, Mac and Linux and [features](https://www.dropbox.com/features) automatic file syncing across multiple machines. You can even hook it into [Growl](http://growl.info/) to see what your collaborators are doing realtime! Best of all, the [basic plan](https://www.dropbox.com/plans) is free and gives you a very generous 2GB of storage. *(Note: should be mentioned to be careful with Dropbox files, as your collaborators could inadvertently destroy your changes. Luckily Dropbox provides some versioning but extra precautions on your end are recommended!)*

Comment: +1 for mentioning Dropbox, this program has been incredibly awesome to me as well.

Comment: Careful using Dropbox for multi-user things though. If two people edit something at the same time, you end up with two copies of it, one renamed. It can cause more trouble than it's worth, to have to open and compare the two copies and hand-merge them. Not that it's Dropbox's fault at all (this is the best thing it could possibly do) but obviously it can't make assumptions and merge things for you like a version control system does. You'd be better off even with something old like CVS (check in, check out) or else you'll replicate it by sending emails: "I'm working on this, don't touch it!"

Comment: Ricket: definitely agree. My GF has been burned by that before and lost a chunk of work. I have added a note to my answer. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3):

For a text-editor which supports multi-user-editing, try [Gobby](http://gobby.0x539.de/trac/),
also there is a project from mozilla labs called [Skywriter](https://mozillalabs.com/skywriter/), which allows you to to embed a multi-user-editor on your website.

Answer (score 2):

[Google Docs](http://docs.google.com/) is one way you can share and edit design documents.

Comment: Google Docs is completely amazing for collaborative editing, especially after the update earlier this year. If only it could become a code editor...

Answer (score 1):

### Alienbrain

[Alienbrain](http://www.alienbrain.com) is one of the only version control systems made for art assets.

Refer to **SO**: [Version Control for Graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29292/version-control-for-graphics)